# Google Universal Analytics doesn't track all visits

Tags: google-analytics

I've implemented Google Universal Analytics a few weeks ago (with user tracking and dimensions) and suddenly the number of tracked unique visitors dropped from 3,000 a day to a handful a day. I can't figure out why GA doesn't track all visits any longer.

Below you see how I track the UserID and how I set `dimension1`. Values for `dimension1` are 'Visitor', 'Admin', 'Customer' and 'Member'.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create','UA-123456-1','auto');
  ga('send','UA-123456-1');
  ga('set','&uid',777);
  ga('set','dimension1','Visitor');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is your exact code (minus the UA ID, of course), then you're not sending any pageviews. You should have

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

but instead you have

```
ga('send', 'UA-123456-1');
```

This would also explain why your dimension1 isn't being set.

Comment: Good catch, probably the solution (hard to tell off the bat). I'll mark it as accepted for now.

Comment: What could explain the handful visitors?

Comment: Spam visits and bots could be visiting your site. Also, could be from specific pages where you do have pageviews set. You can easily verify your code by copying and pasting the exact code (with the right UA ID) into a console window and see what hits are sent (this is what I did to test it).

Comment: Plus the dimension need be set before the send pageview-Call (they need an interaction like pageview or event to be transmitted to the tracking server).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Are you saying that ga('send', 'pageview'); needs to be placed towards the very end of the script?

Comment: Yes, the hit (pageview, event, timing, transaction) needs to be sent after the dimension has been set.